# Сравнение двух массивов с объектами

Tags: javascript, массивы

Существует два массива:

```
const arr1 = [
  {id:1},
  {id:2},
  {id:3},
  {id:4}
]

const arr2 = [
  {id:1},
  {id:4},
  {id:5},
]
```

Мне необходимо сравнить два массива и создать третий из объектов, в которых id совпадает, т.е. `arr3=[{id:1},{id:4}]`

Я пользуюсь простым перебором обоих мссивов, но думаю, это долго:

```
arr1.forEach((item) => {
            arr2.forEach((item2) => {
                if (item.id == item2.id) {
                    arr3.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, наиболее  быстрое выполнение. Спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос, массивы отсортированы, и id у них числовые? Можно ли строить алгоритм на том, что id - это 1,2,3 и т.д. Или же они могуть быть разнообразные? В зависимости от ответа, могут быть разные алгоритмы по производительности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тяжело представить вычисление пересечения массива без переобходов. Единственное, что могу предложить - сократить количество операций.

Для начала, стоит определить самый маленький массив, так как результирующий массив не будет больше самого маленького, но позволит сократить количество обходов для ряда значений, которые есть в большем, но отсутствуют в меньшем массиве. Это позволит убрать push и использовать filter.

Вторым этапом, нам нет нужды во втором массива обходить его весь, как у вас. Достаточно первого совпадения, в этом нам поможет some. Таким образом мы гарантированно обойдем оба массива только когда нет ни одного соответствия. В случае с совпадением, мы выйдем при первом же совпадении.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 }
]

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 5 },
]

const leastArr = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
const biggestArr = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;

const resultArray = leastArr.filter((item) => {
  return biggestArr.some((item2) => item2.id === item.id)
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: бОльший массив находить не обязательно. Конечный результат не может быть больше наименьшего массива.

Comment: Да, согласен, это лишнее требование. Видимо задумался, спасибо. В теории, использование меньшего массива будет более оптимальным решением для фильтрации.

Comment: @PavelNazarian спасибо, отредактировал ответ. Действительно так будет лучше.

Comment: Можно чуток сократить: `const [leastArr, biggestArr] = [arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);` или `const [leastArr, biggestArr] = (arr1.length < arr2.length) ? [arr1, arr2] : [arr2, arr1];` (второе длиннее но производительнее). То есть, сейчас по сути дважды проверяется одно условие... Но хз, насколько тяжелее эта вторая проверка операции создания промежуточного массива - вполне может оказаться что дважды проверить выходит экономичнее :)

Comment: @yar85 можно, не спорю. Но деструктуризация крайне медленная операция. Сравните тесткейсы https://jsbench.me/b8kupfu2fl/1 - вы увидите, что деструктуризация процентов на 80 медленее

Comment: @PZBird, верно, спасибо за тест.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сократить переборы за счёт вспомогательной структуры, но нужно тестировать, будет ли выигрыш. Из одного массива можно создать Set наличных идентификаторов, тогда при проходе по второму массиву можно будет дишь проверять наличие идентирфикатора в Set, это быстрее, чем перебирать массив. В итогде на всё потребуется только по одному перебору на каждый массив, но будут расходы на создание Set и проверки в нём.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id:1},
  {id:2},
  {id:3},
  {id:4}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id:1},
  {id:4},
  {id:5},
];

const set = new Set();
for (const { id } of arr1) set.add(id);

const intersection = arr2.filter(({ id }) => set.has(id));
console.log(intersection);
```